# Unable to keep sticky item fixed on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page in which a sidebar remains fixed on scroll
in http://vidyaprabodhinicollege.edu.in/VPCCECM/BCom.php
i.e. Categories sidebar 
but towards including it in http://vidyaprabodhinicollege.edu.in/VPCCECM/BCom/index.php
the sidebar doesnt remain fixed.
Would like to know how do i resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: @D s Back Check errors in developer console

Comment: Check my answer for solution. Please mark as solved once you've updated it :)

Comment: Yes that worked.... thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Update this reference in your theme

```
<!-- Vendor -->
<script src="../http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change it to

```
<!-- Vendor -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please check your console errors on

http://vidyaprabodhinicollege.edu.in/VPCCECM/BCom/index.php

Here's a screenshot

[image]

There's a function inside "theme.js" that isn't firing because of the console errors (jQuery isn't being loaded). I'll quickly see if I can find out why.